# pytest cannot find Module due to similar package name in dependencies

Tags: python, pytest

I started with Python a month back and I am working on a Python project with below package structure:

- Package in project: `"xyz.a.b.c.d"`
- Package of dependent modules: `"xyz.a.b.c"` and `"xyz.a.b.e"`

While running tests using pytest, I get a  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xyz.a.b.c.d'`. When I add `__init__` to each of the folders i.e. xyz, a, b and c (d already has a `__init__`) then  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xyz.a.b.e'`

How do I go about resolving this?

UPDATE:
There was a `__init__.py` inside "xyz.a.b.c" after removing which the issue is resolved. Wondering if while running pytest, due to init, the dependencies hides any sub package from dependent project or other libraries?

Comment: is there an init in the e directory?

Comment: No, there is no init in the e directory